# Is use count on `const std::shared_ptr<...>' mutable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to adapt some pre-existing code to make use of std::shared_ptr<...>. It is a `message passing system' so the basic context is:

Public Method:

```
void writeReport(std::shared_ptr<const ReportBase> pReport) {
  /* This is a public method for writing a report. I might do
     additional stuff in here but end by forwarding to the
     private method. */
  writeReport_(pReport);
}
```

Private Method:

```
void writeReport_(std::shared_ptr<const ReportBase> pReport) {
  if( certain conditions )
    processReport_(pReport);

  writeBytes_(serialize(pReport));
}
```

Processing Method:

```
void processReport_(std::shared_ptr<const ReportBase> pReport) {
  processReportImpl(pReport);

  if( certain other conditions )
    reportDeque_.push_back(pReport);
}
```

Of the above pseudo-code, for example, processReport_(...) might be the only method which, under certain conditions, would want to actually store the record. The other methods are simply interested in the contents of the object pointed to. So, were it not for the need to sometimes copy the shared_ptr in `processReport_(...)` (i.e., 'store' the record), I would simply pass `const ReportBase *` to all my nested functions and avoid the overhead of pass-by-value (i.e., use count increments).

So, I want to pass `std::shared_ptr<const ReportBase>&` (and maybe `&&` where appropriate) but want to preclude some rogue nested method from actually modifying what the pointer points to. So I think I want to pass `const std::shared_ptr<const ReportBase>&` to prevent that...

... but, again, in `processReport_(...)` I'll sometimes want to make a copy to store the record.

Which finally leads me to the question(s)...

- is use count on a std::shared_ptr mutable?
- Why can (or can't) I do a copy assignment on a `const std::shared_ptr<...>` to a `std::shared_ptr<...>`?
- Does the `const` make the entire control block of the shared_ptr `const`? Or does the leading `const` only apply to the raw pointer value?

And if someone wants to answer tangentially 'don't worry so much about passing by value into nested functions' or 'I have a completely different approach for you' then I'd be interested to hear that too.

Comment: Sounds all very confused.

Comment: I suppose it boils down to ... can I do a copy assignment from a const std::shared_ptr<...>& and have it do the 'right thing'?

And if I can, why can I do that? Certainly, incrementing the use count on a shared_ptr modifies the object ... which seems to violate the constness... unless use count is mutable.

Comment: Have a lookup on `std::weak_ptr` where you don't intend to increase the reference count.

Comment: I know about `std::weak_ptr`and that's not what I'm asking about. What I'm trying to understand is... when I have a `std::shared_ptr<...>` and I make a copy of it, the use count is incremented in its control block. So, if I make a copy of a `const std::shared_ptr<...>` then the effect is to modify the object (by changing the use count). So, is the control block mutable? Why is it that I can make a copy of a `const std::shared_ptr<...>` when making the copy, in some sense, modifies the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` stores a pointer to the control block, which is allocated on the heap. After all, it has to be shared across all copies of that `shared_ptr`. So, when you apply a `const` to your `std::shared_ptr`, you are merely making that pointer `const`. The control block object being pointed to remains non-const. Think `ControlBlock* const`. Therefore, there is no need for an explicit `mutable` keyword there, although logically, the control block is indeed mutable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I would use a function like this

```
void processReport(const std::shared_ptr<ReportBase> &report) {

    if( certain other condition ) {
        reportDeque_.push_back(report); // will make the copy here
}
```

With the `const std::shared_ptr<ReportBase> &` you don't increment the use count, so if you add it to the vector it will have to be a copy of the shared_prt and therefore increase the count, if not the count stays the same.

Comment: Okay... so I can just do that... and the effect is that I increment the use count on `report` just like if I had passed a non-const argument into processReport?

It just seems like the use count increment that I get from making a copy of a std::shared_ptr would violate the `const`-ness of it... so either the use count is mutable or the control block isn't made const...

Comment: Well, it depends what you want, the idea of a shared pointer is that you can have multiple instances owning the element. So all you can do with a const shared pointer is to prevent the overhead of increasing and decrease the count everytime you call or leave the function. If on the other hand you want to prevent a second pointer on the object, shared pointer ist the wrong choice, then you better use a `unique_pt`. A unique pointer prevents the function from creating a copy, if you really want to add it to the vector you have to move it to it, so there is really always just one pointer to it.