# Passing shared_ptr to function - clarification needed

Tags: c++

I have a class with the member

```
vector<shared_ptr<ParticleSystem>> particleSystems;
```

which has a method

```
void AddParticleSystem(shared_ptr<ParticleSystem> const sys)
{
    particleSystems.push_back(sys);
}
```

note the parameter. 
The method is called like so:

```
shared_ptr<ParticleSystem> psys = make_shared<ParticleSystem>(...);
scene.AddParticleSystem(psys);
```

**It works, but why? Doesn't this get shared?**

---

By default I don't try to pass around pointers. When considering function parameters, I either use `const&` when wish not to change anything on the passed variable or use `&` when plan to use methods that will change members of the given variable.

So By default I implemented the above method like so:

```
void AddParticleSystem(ParticleSystem const& sys)
{
    particleSystems.push_back(std::make_shared<ParticleSystem>(sys));
}
```

that I call like

```
shared_ptr<ParticleSystem> psys = make_shared<ParticleSystem>(...);
scene.AddParticleSystem(*psys);
```

This time it doesn't compile, stating

> Error C2280   'Physics::ParticleSystem::ParticleSystem(const
>   Physics::ParticleSystem &)': attempting to reference a deleted
>   function

I traced back the issue using `Output` (I use VS) which has led me to

```
particleSystems.push_back(std::make_shared<ParticleSystem>(sys));
```

to the `make_shared` method, to be precise.

Now, This `ParticleSystem` extends `Visual` that has constructors and members like

```
Visual(string const &name, string const &path, const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath, const char* geometryPath = nullptr, bool gamma = false)
{
    this->name = string().append(name);
    model = make_unique<Model>(path, gamma);
    material = make_unique<Material>();
    shader = make_unique<Shader>(vertexPath, fragmentPath, geometryPath);
}

unique_ptr<Shader> shader;
unique_ptr<Material> material;
unique_ptr<Model> model;
virtual ~Visual() = default;
```

**I get `make_shared` needs to copy stuff somehow. Is the problem that a `ParticleSystem` which is a `Visual` has `unique_ptr` members and by default `make_shared` knows not how to treat them?**

Is this the reason the compiler deleted my default copy constructor? And if so, if I implement a copy constructor for all the classes that `Visual` has, including itself, I can pass that `ParticleSystem const&` as a parameter?

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the edit.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the object? Whats the shared pointer doing if not sharing?

Comment: I wish not to copy it, just share (have two classes with similar lifetime to share the ownership). Which parameter would copy? the `shared_ptr<ParticleSystem> const` or the `ParticleSystem const&`?

Comment: Both would copy, but one copies the `shared_ptr`, the other copies the `ParticleSystem`.

Comment: I guess the `shared_ptr<ParticleSystem> const` copies the shared pointer itself (which points to the object). If I want to share **the object** and NOT copy it, does copying around the `shared_ptr` (the first, working solution) cut it?

Comment: Where is your [MCVE] please?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776400/passing-a-shared-pointer-by-reference-or-by-value-as-parameter-to-a-class/49776497#49776497)

Comment: @PaulSanders The question is kind of theoretical (as I don't fully understand how this passing around smart pointers work), not a debug-my-code one. To give a complete example I would have to pass _a lot of_ code.

Comment: @MikeVine so you say I should just pass a copy of the `shared_ptr` (it's fine by me :D )? Does the `std::move` require some copy constructors implemented?

Comment: If you wish to share it, why are you marking it as `const`?

Comment: @Eljay valid claim, my bad, sorry. Went with the `shared_ptr<ParticleSystem> const&` solution as stated in the answer.

Comment: A coworker of mine wrote up a good guide on shared_ptr, unique_ptr, raw pointer, reference usage:  [GotW #91 Solution: Smart Pointer Parameters](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each copy of a `shared_ptr` is a handle by which the shared object can be accessed. You can pass around references to the `shared_ptr` or copies of it and store copies of it in collections. Copies of `shared_ptr`s refer to the same underlying object. When the last `shared_ptr` that refers to the same underlying object is destroyed, the underlying object is destroyed.

Comment: So when I pass it like `shared_ptr<ParticleSystem>` to the function, before calling I have share count 1, then while passing I have 2, then during the `AddParticleSystem` method I have 3, then after that 2 (as the parameter ended) right?

Comment: @agiro That's correct. To avoid the extra increment/decrement, you could pass it by const reference (or move it into the collection).

Comment: Thank you, will do that (though the program isn't multithreaded so I wouldn't have to worry that much about inc/dec, but one never knows). By the way, Why doesn't the `ParticleSystem&` work?

Comment: @agiro Because that tries to construct a new `ParticleSystem` as a copy of the one passed by reference, and `ParticleSystem` is uncopyable as its copy constructor is deleted.

Comment: Two more question if I may - 1. It tried to copy because (from the reference) it has an address _of an object_ only and still has to forge the `shared_ptr` for the `vector`? 
2. when I implement the copy constructor, I can pass my object around like that. _but I will get a new object and if I change that one, the original will not be affected?_

Comment: @agiro think of your call `= std::make_shared<ParticleSystem>(sys)` as the same thing as `= std::shared_ptr<ParticleSystem>( new ParticleSystem(sys))` and you can see why the copy constructor is being called. These two calls are effectively the same thing.