# Smart pointer declared const

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Smart pointers declared `const` could only invoke the member functions marked with `const`. So their usage is very limited.

1.For unique pointers, you could not [change the transfer the ownership of the managed object to another `unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and not even return it from a specific function.

So my question is that when `const unique_ptr<T>` should be used? Some simple example may help me to understand it better.

2.For shared pointers, I think it's meaningless to use `const shared_ptr<T>` because you can never increase the counter of a specific const shared pointer.
If I wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is use count on \`const std::shared\_ptr<...>' mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830481/is-use-count-on-const-stdshared-ptr-mutable)  In summary, the shared_ptr stores a constant pointer to a non-const control block which is allocated on the heap and the control block contains the counter.  So a const shared_ptr just means that the pointer to the control block doesn't change.  No biggy - still works.

Answer (score 1):

Re: Non-transferrable unique pointers

Yes, that's the point.  If you have a const object you cannot modify it.  Transferring ownership of a pointer either from or to a const `unique_ptr` is therefore not allowed.

Example:

```
struct ResourceUser {
    ResourceUser() : mResource(CoupleMeWithSomeResource(this)) {}
private:
    const unique_ptr<SomeResource> mResource;
};
```

Now an instance of `ResourceUser` outright owns a resource that is in some way linked back to this object's address.  You don't ever want that object to move in memory.  Without needing any additional syntax, something like `ResourceUser a, b; a = move(b);` is disallowed.  Yaay!

> Not even return it from a specific function

The only useful reason to return a unique pointer from a function is when you have created some value that is passed back to the caller or you are yielding ownership of something -- actually these are the same thing.  It makes no sense to make it const.  So yeah, irrelevant.  Don't use a hammer to drive in a screw.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand ` mResource(CoupleMeWithSomeResource(this))`. What's `CoupleMeWithSomeResource(this)`? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: It's an imaginary function that acquires some kind of resource that is in some way tied to the object that acquired it (_e.g._ by way of storing a back-pointer) and returns a unique pointer.  Such an imaginary scenario might involve events being sent to the owner.  This type of pattern is not particularly uncommon.

Comment: ***This type of pattern is not particularly uncommon.*** What's the name of the aforementioned design pattern. Could you please show me a simple example to understand it better?

Answer (score 0):

One potential use-case would be when you've called a function that returns a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` to you, and you want the compiler to guarantee that the access to that object can't escape your function, e.g.:

```
void Foo()
{
   // tagging blah as const to be sure that
   // no reference to the object blah points
   // to will be retained after this function
   // returns
   const unique_ptr<Bar> blah = getBar();

   [...]

   someGlobalVariable = blah;  // compile-time error -- nice try!
}
```

... as for *why* you'd want to do that... Foo() might do something that will make future access to `*blah` unsafe, and so the best way to avoid unpleasant runtime bugs is to have the compiler ensure that those accesses cannot happen, even if someone modifies your function to try to allow it.  Code that can defends itself against future maintenance programmers is less likely to gather bugs :)